# XML Files To Web Form with .net

Tags: c#, xml

now i am assigned to web project,that used asp.net mvc with c#.
i need to load some XML file like below and that will tell which controls i need to create.
This also tells,type of controls,their value,size and location.i can't find the way how i do?please guide me right way.

```
 <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.Form" name="frmShow" >
  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton" name="optOne">    
    <Property name="Size">86, 24</Property>    
    <Property name="Text">Option1</Property>
    <Property name="Location">175, 126</Property>    
  </Object>

  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox" name="chkOne">
    <Property name="Size">84, 24</Property>
    <Property name="Text">CheckOne</Property>
    <Property name="Location">84, 126</Property>  
  </Object>

  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" name="txtOne">
    <Property name="Size">177, 20</Property>
    <Property name="Text">ABC</Property>
    <Property name="Location">84, 88</Property>  
  </Object>

  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.Label" name="lblOne">
    <Property name="Size">100, 23</Property>
    <Property name="Text">Name</Property>
    <Property name="Location">8, 91</Property>  
  </Object>

  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" name="txtTwo">
    <Property name="Size">177, 20</Property>
    <Property name="Text">Home Address</Property>
    <Property name="Location">84, 50</Property>    
  </Object>

  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.Label" name="lblTwo">
    <Property name="Size">100, 23</Property>
    <Property name="Text">Address</Property>
    <Property name="Location">7, 53</Property>  
  </Object>

  <ItemDataSet>
    <ItemTable>      
      <TableName>tblItemOne</TableName>
      <Row1>
        <Repeat>True</Repeat>
        <ItemName>Item001</ItemName>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
        <Price>1000</Price>
      </Row1>
      <Row2>
        <Repeat>True</Repeat>
        <ItemName>Item002</ItemName>
        <Qty>20</Qty>
        <Price>2000</Price>
      </Row2>
      <Row3>
        <Repeat>false</Repeat>
      <ItemName>Item003</ItemName>
      <Qty>30</Qty>
      <Price>3000</Price>
      </Row3>      
    </ItemTable>    
  </ItemDataSet>

</Object>
```

Comment: It might be a webform that was serialized into xaml. Try deserializing it.

Comment: can you explain me detail?Actually,i am not familiar with webform.please give me some examples or link,thanks.

Comment: The XmlSerializer can turn objects into XML. Your XML could be an object that was serialized.
If it is, you can deserialize the XML, and turn it into an object. It might not be the case but
it is worth a look.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code creates a dictionary of controls. You can optimize it further if you need.
Another alternative is to create a schema (xsd) based on the xml and then use XmlSerializer as suggested by @Jon Abaca. The XmlSerializer option is much simpler than this approach.

**First approach (without XmlSerializer)**

```
private Dictionary GetControlDictionary(string xmlFilePath)
{
    Dictionary controlsDictionary = new Dictionary();
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form));    
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath))
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        XmlNodeList xmlNodesList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Object");                        
        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodesList)
        {
            if (xmlNode.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                string typeName = xmlNode.Attributes["type"].Value;
                string objectName = xmlNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                Type controlType = assembly.GetType(typeName);
                if (controlType != null)
                {
                    object controlObject = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
                    if (controlObject is Control)
                    {
                        Control control = controlObject as Control;
                        control.Name = objectName;
                        controlsDictionary.Add(objectName, control);
                        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (string.Equals("Property", childNode.Name))
                            {
                                string propertyName = childNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                                string propertyValue = childNode.InnerText;
                                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = controlType.GetProperty(propertyName);
                                if (propertyInfo != null)
                                {
                                    if(propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Size))
                                    {
                                        string width = propertyValue.Split(new char[] {','})[0];
                                        string height = propertyValue.Split(new char[] {','})[1];
                                        System.Drawing.Size size = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(width), Convert.ToInt32(height));
                                        propertyInfo.SetValue(control, size, null);
                                    }
                                    else if(propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Point))
                                    {
                                        string x = propertyValue.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0];
                                        string y = propertyValue.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0];                                        System.Drawing.Point point = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
                                        propertyInfo.SetValue(control, point, null);
                                    }
                                    else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                                    {
                                        propertyInfo.SetValue(control, propertyValue, null);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                            
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return controlsDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert this scala code for C# or even you can consume the Scale in c# Refer to http://code.google.com/p/xsd-forms/

Also you can use [XSLTViewEngine](http://nuget.org/packages/XsltViewEngine)

[XSD Form built based on Scala](http://code.google.com/p/xsd-forms/)