# Creating a Web Form from an XML Description of It

Tags: asp.net, xml

i am assigned to web part of some project.My duty is to create web form from xml.
These xml comes from window part and tells which controls are include in my web form and their properties.My xml Format is like below.

```
<Object type="System.Windows.Forms.Form">
  <Property name="Name">Form1</Property>
  <Property name="Text">Option</Property>  
  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton">    
    <Property name="Name">RadioButton1</Property>
    <Property name="Size">86, 24</Property>    
    <Property name="Text">RadioButton1</Property>
    <Property name="Location">175, 126</Property>    
  </Object>
  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox">
    <Property name="Name">CheckBox1</Property>
    <Property name="Size">84, 24</Property>    
    <Property name="Text">Accept</Property>
    <Property name="Location">84, 126</Property>    
  </Object>
  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox">
    <Property name="Name">TextBox1</Property>
    <Property name="Size">177, 20</Property>  1
    <Property name="Text">Singapore</Property>    
    <Property name="Location">84, 88</Property>    
  </Object>    
  <Object type="System.Windows.Forms.Label">
    <Property name="Name">Label1</Property>
    <Property name="Size">100, 23</Property>
    <Property name="Text">Name</Property>
    <Property name="Location">7, 53</Property>    
  </Object>  
  <DataSet1>
    <Table1>
      <TableName>TableOne</TableName>
      <ItemName>item001</ItemName>
      <Qty>100</Qty>
      <Price>1000</Price>
    </Table1>
    <Table2>
      <TableName>TableTwo</TableName>
      <ItemName>item002</ItemName>
      <Qty>200</Qty>
      <Price>2000</Price>
    </Table2>
  </DataSet1>
</Object>
```

what is the best way to solve my problem? i found some people used
XmlSerialization, so, can i use this way or is there any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Files To Web Form with C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447404/xml-files-to-web-form-with-c-net)

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447404/xml-files-to-web-form-with-c-net

Comment: yes,friend,it is not quite different from my earlier question.i want to know other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I hope you don't expect to be adding Windows Forms controls onto your web form.
2. This doesn't make much sense. You will not only need to create a web form - you also need to be able to create code to handle events from the controls on the form. I don't see anything in your XML that describes that.

Comment: sorry,i forget to say something,my web form is only for show.It's look like template.No need to handle events.

Comment: Did you know that ASP.NET is basically a description in XML?

Comment: sorry,i don't know.please tell me.my project is used in asp.net mvc.

Comment: They why do you even want do do this XML nonsense? Just create your forms like normal people do.

Comment: Actually is some users will create their own template in window part like visual studio IDE.And then they need to view their template in web part for some case.thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you aware of XSLT (XML Stylesheet and Transform)? An XML-based language that allows you to transform XML from one shape to another? Like from your XML template definition into an XHTML form?

Comment: to tell you the truth,i am not sure which way i can use.i can't touch window part and i have only this xml file.so,can you show me some examples,please.

Comment: You don't need examples. Your team needs a better analysis of the requirements, or you need to explain them better. Are you trying to create a web version of a Windows Form? To do what with? Just look at it?